# Codeigniter 3.0 subdomain configuration causing 404 errors

Tags: php, codeigniter

On my localhost my project works perfectly. I created my [subdomain](http://licenta.attila-naghi.com/) and I get the 404 errors. This is my phpinfo : [here](http://licenta.attila-naghi.com/info.php).

This is my htaccess content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]  
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Other information: the db connection it is ok. The route.php content is this:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

The config.php content:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://licenta.attila-naghi.com/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
$config['language'] = 'english';
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
$config['composer_autoload'] = FALSE;
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
$config['function_trigger'] = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger'] = 'd';
$config['log_threshold'] = 0;
$config['log_path'] = '';
$config['log_file_extension'] = '';
$config['log_file_permissions'] = 0644;
$config['log_date_format'] = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
```

......... If you need the rest of them please ask.

Can anyone help with this error 404 on my subdomain ? thx

Comment: do you any suggestion  ?

Comment: the only suggestion is mod_rewrite not configured on server

Comment: well i change the name of my controller, from home.php to Home.php and now i am getting a db connection error. I don't know why because i gave it the right data

Comment: try to open db with phpMyAdmin, for example, to test your db configuration data

Answer (score 0):

Try this... You need to specify your RewriteBase to suit the subfolder  that you have your subdomain saved under.

So if you have your site saved under the folder licenta you would have...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /licenta
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]  
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

when upgrading a CodeIgniter app to version 3.0 or higher, any file that contains a class must be renamed to start with a capital letter (controllers, models, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Mainly this type of error because of htaccess .
you can find cause of error in server by showing error on **error_log**